# How Anopheles crop doesn't digest gametocytes of P. vivax?

Tags: biochemistry, digestion, host-pathogen-interaction, malaria

### **Background**

According to my A-level textbook: When *Anopheles* mosquitoes inject their proboscises and suck up blood from human host of malaria agent, they suck all stages of malaria parasite present in the blood like merozoites, cryptozoites, gametocytes etc.
But, *Anopheles* mosquito's crop digests all other stages of malaria schizogony except the gametocytes.

### **Question**

Well, how does the digestive system of *Anopheles* distinguish the gametocytes from other stages of malaria parasite?
Or, is there any protective mechanism for gametocytes to stay untouched in face of digestion in *Anopheles* crop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short Answer:** Nothing prevents it, most *Plasmodium* (gametocytes/gametes/zygotes/ookinetes) *are* killed.

**Background:** After lots of search, I finally found a definite answer about this. According to [Smith *et al*, 2014](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4156458/), the survival rate of *Plasmodium* in the *Anopheles* gut is very low. At each developmental step during their life cycle, a large proportion of *Plasmodium* face the deleterious effects of the gut (albeit they are not certain that the effect possesses contribution from enzymes). As an example, even if an *Anopheles* mosquito ingests thousands of *Plasmodium* gametocytes, about 50-100 are able to develop into ookinetes while only about five survive to form oocyst. This is why even in high transmission areas, majority of *Anopheles* mosquitoes are not infected by *Plasmodium* parasites. See this image:

[image: Plasmodium bottlenecks]

Pay attention to 'parasite #' and see how the number of parasites keeps on decreasing during different stages of development of *Plasmodium*.

**Reference:** [Smith RC, Vega-Rodríguez J, Jacobs-Lorena M. The *Plasmodium* bottleneck: malaria parasite losses in the mosquito vector. *Memórias do Instituto Oswaldo Cruz.* 2014;109(5):644-661. doi:10.1590/0074-0276130597](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4156458/)

Comment: Perhaps worth emphasising the points made in the paper (and shown in the Figure you have reproduced) that much of the reduction in parasite numbers may be attributable to factors present in the blood bolus such as complement, that come from the blood meal.

Comment: Why is there a sudden increase after a continuous decrease? O, I get it it's cleavage in epithelium.

Comment: @Another After this answer, do you still think the primary host of *Plasmodium* is *Anopheles*? I don't think without paleontological data, nothing can be said about which was the prior host of *Plasmodium*, mammal or *Anopheles*

Comment: "blood bolus such as complement, that come from the blood meal." Do you mean complements from human blood?" Do you mean complement proteins gathered from human host blood? @Alan Boyd

Comment: @Mockingbird yes, the paper that is linked to in the answer includes extensive discussion of the role of human complement in killing during the early stages - it is shown in the diagram along with blood-derived antibodies. The article also suggests a role for reactive nitrogen species generated  by incoming haemoglobin, amongst other things.

Comment: @alanboyd the paper said that the gametocytes (inside bolus) are resistant to complememnts while ookinetes (which come out when complements and bolus are digested) are sensitive to complements. Enlighten me if I got this wrong, but this is why I didn't bother to add it.

Comment: @mockingbird well I don't specialize in this field, so I can't say anything definitely

Comment: @another'Homosapien' I thought that you had broadened the scope of the discussion beyond gametocytes. If you didn't mean to do that then fine, but looking at the information in the Figure I don't think it is fair to say that 'most of them are killed' if 'them' means gametocytes only.

Comment: 'nitrogen species' What kind of nitrogen species? @Alam

Comment: @Mockingbird why not read the paper?

Comment: Okay. I will do it

Comment: @alanboyd nope I didn't mean to broaden the topic, 'them' meant _Plasmodium_ in general, not just gametocytes (does it convey that meaning?)

Answer (score 4):

**Disclaimer:** I am trying to answer the question without finding any academic research on the topic. So, appreciate hypotheses and feel free to point out mistakes.

**Short Answer : Co- Evolution**

---

**Broad Answer:** 2 hypotheses

1. The gamete stage of Malaria parasite simply co-evolved with *Anopheles* sp. to develop a protective mechanism to survive digestion in crop. Whereas, the other stages of Malaria parasite didn't co-evolve,  so they get digested.
2. Parasites had already the protective mechanism for surviving digestive enzymes in *Anopheles* crop. They entered mammals later and evolved a life cycle with a new protective mechanism for new host's immune system.

**Why is that?**

The answer to this question is not so clear according to known biology, as I haven't found much research in this phenomenon. 
But, we have to remember that biology sometimes (*or always?*) doesn't explain *why* rather explain *how*.

**The following words are corresponding to what I think about the mechanism of this co-evolution**

**Hypothesis 1:** 
It could have simply happened that some point in ancient times, the gamete entered the *Anopheles* crop from a mammal, but not only that; it tried to continue its life cycle on this new host. But, the environment of crop was unsuitable for the gamete to survive due tto digestive enzymes. So, the first few million or billion tries went into vain. But, the parasite slowly started to evolve to adopt in the *Anopheles* crop.

After 'some' time, the parasite developed a working protective mechanism from digestive enzymes and continued it's life cycle in *Anopheles*.

As @Another Home sapien points out, there should be some benefits for this evolution. While it's hard to tell exactly what the benefits could have been; I think it's simply to adopt to new potential host's physiological environment.

**But why didn't other stages evolve of Malaria parasite in a same way?**

This is another hard question to answer. However, it's not so that only the *Anopheles* and the parasite co-evolve; the mammal host co-evolved too in this period. And the whole system evolved gradually to get to the present life-cycle of malaria.

**Hypothesis 2:**

It might have happened that the original host to malaria parasite was indeed *Anopheles*. So, it had developed a protective mechanism long before entering any mammal host. Then, after entering the mammal host it developed another protective mechanism to survive host's immune system and continued  it's life cycle.

I think hypothesis 2 is more probable as insects pre-existed mammals. Another hypothesis can be drawn the life cycle of parasite is shaped up simultaneously in mammal host and *Anopheles* host. But, it's hard to hypothesize what could have happened in this scenario.

Reference : 1. [Wiki: Co-Evolution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coevolution)

2.[Article on this co-evolution](http://www.abc.net.au/science/news/stories/s832491.htm)

Comment: I must say, you are assuming just too much in your answer. How do you know that _Anopheles_ wasn't the original host of _Plasmodium_? And what benefit would sporozoites get even if they developed a protection against digestive enzymes? In evolution, selection pressure can be both _in favor of_ **or** _against_ a trait. Also, I won't recommend using phrases like "it chose to..." Also, usually its the parasite that co-evolves with the host, while the host just _evolves_ to get rid of that parasite (which _Anopheles_ too seems to be doing now)...

Comment: Thank you @Another You are free to edit my 'answer'. I too felt that my understanding is limited in this case. So, I will edit now.

Comment: @Another Do you think you would be able to add some quality reference on this phenomenon?

Comment: well, I've already been searching for the 'how' part for hours :P regarding the 'why' part, I'd love to improve the answer, but I feel I should first wait for somebody more specialized in evolutionary biology (since I ain't)...

Comment: @Mockingbird Just as an additional information: the definitive host of *Plasmodium* is the mosquito, **not** the mammal.

Comment: @Gerarddo Furtado Thank you for your comment. I hope you can add some reference and details to my answer.

Comment: @Gerardo Are you sure about it?

Comment: Yes, totally. Do you know what a *definitive* host is? I used to warn my students to this detail all the time: the definitive host of *Trypanosoma* is the fly, humans are only secondary hosts; the definitive host of *Anopheles* is the mosquito, humans are only secondary hosts... maybe the fact that humans consider themselves so important has something to do with this common, yet incorrect, conception that we are the primary hosts for those parasites.

Comment: Then, the 2nd hypothesis is more probable, I think.

Comment: @Mockingbird indeed a very imprtant & essential question to ask...@Gerardo Furtado said its totally correct.The Plasmodium's primary host is the Anopheles.There r reasons why but this logic is merely basic level only:The encysment of oocyst is due to partially secretion of cyst material by the stomach of the primary host and partially by the zygote itself.Without encystment sporogony doesnot initiate in them. This could be an important phenomenon which makes the mosquito not just a vector but a vector host.Otherwise they could hve cmpleted the entire cycle in humans alone.

Comment: I just realised that I wrote *"the definitive host of Anopheles is the mosquito"*, what I meant was: *"the definitive host of Plasmodium is the mosquito"*.

Comment: @Catharanthus What's the difference between vector and vector host?

Comment: vectors only transmit the disease and vector hosts not only transmits the disease but also plays the role of a host during one phase of a digenetic life cycle like in malaria.I only read the term in a textbook on a digenetic cycle.

Comment: Would I have to award the bounty to myself?

Comment: What if Nobody answers without me? Would I have to award the bounty to me?

Comment: Umm sadly AFAIK you cannot award a bounty to yourself. Its probably gonna go to nowhere.

Comment: @Another Ha Broke my heart

Comment: Sorry for that, but now you have another option :P

Comment: @another'Homosapien' and Mockingbird: There is a reason why you cannot award the bounty to yourself (in any SE site). Suppose this situation: 1. You post a question and start a bounty of 500 (the maximum allowed). 2. People do a good research, excited about those 500 virtual whatever. 3. You get one or more well written, extensively documented answer. 4. You post your own, crappy answer. 5. You benefit from the canonical answer but award yourself the bounty, not loosing any point.

Comment: @gerardofurtado lol :P yeah that would be injustice with the whole purpose of bounty

Comment: @Furtado I understand.